# How do I run Locust Load Distributed testing on AWS EC2 without running multiple sessions?

Tags: amazon-web-services, python-3.7, locust

I'm trying to run a Locust test via EC2 but am running into high CPU usage problems. I would like to distribute the load via master-slave processes but is there a way to do it without creating multiple EC2's and logging into each one and running commands? The closest thing I found was:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/using-locust-on-aws-elastic-beanstalk-for-distributed-load-generation-and-testing/

Here they use Elastic Beanstalk but some of the info seems quite dated.

Comment: Which commands did you try and what are the results? Did you tried like this? https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/running-locust-distributed.html

Comment: Yes, I tried the master-slave option as mentioned in the docs - with a master machine and multiple worker machines. It works as intended but requires me to create and log into each virtual machine and run commands - I was wondering if there was a different way to approach this without having to do that, as mentioned in the original question.

Comment: Good. I'm not sure but using tmux in ec2 terminal might work. In tmux we can use multi sessions/windows which have the same ip address.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I think I would still have to create multiple EC2 instances, install script, run commands to get it all set up. Is there a way to scale out like EB?

Comment: Have you had a look at https://github.com/SvenskaSpel/locust-swarm ?

Comment: @Cyberwiz Not entirely sure how it differs from the provided functionality from the original master-worker documentation but also does not seem to eliminate the need of having to connect onto multiple EC2s (at least not specified in docs).

Answer (score 0):

You can use .sh script like this to activate slave nodes

```
#!/bin/bash

# Replace MASTER_IP with the private IP address of the Locust master
MASTER_IP="YourMasterPrivateIPAddress"

# Get the private IP addresses of the slave nodes using AWS CLI (replace the TagKey and TagValue accordingly)
SLAVE_IPS=$(aws ec2 describe-instances --filters "Name=tag:YourTagKey,Values=YourTagValue" --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].PrivateIpAddress' --output text)

# Start Locust on each slave node
for IP in $SLAVE_IPS; do
    ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" ec2-user@$IP "locust -f /path/to/your_locust_script.py --slave --master-host=$MASTER_IP &"
done
```